# rectangle class in java using only 2 points

Tags: java

I'm writing a Rectangle class and it has 2 instance variables which are 2 points that are called _pointSW and _pointNE. I have to define the width and the height of the rectangle, but I can't use any other variables besides the 2 points.

I want to ask how I could write the `getWidth()` method, for example using just the _pointNE, or maybe better write a private method (because I can't use any new public methods) to define the width and the height, and then use it in other methods and if that's an option, then how do I actually write it? thanks!

Comment: please edit the question and show your code

Comment: What does your code look like so far? What exactly do you have problem with? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Can you do this on paper ?

Comment: Points will likely have an x and y coordinate, which usually start at 0, 0, and increases to the right and bottom. Then `width` will be `ne.x - sw.x` and `height` will be `sw.y - ne.y`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i setup a variable inside a constructor and use a "getter" method later on in the program on it? (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70059720/how-can-i-setup-a-variable-inside-a-constructor-and-use-a-getter-method-later)

Answer (score 4):

If your SW means South-West and NE means North-East:

```
public class Tuple<X, Y> { 
  public final X x; 
  public final Y y; 
  public Tuple(X x, Y y) { 
    this.x = x; 
    this.y = y; 
  } 
} 

public class Rectangle {
  private Tuple<double,double> pointSW;
  private Tuple<double,double> pointNE;

  public Rectangle(final Tuple<double,double> sw, final Tuple<double,double> ne) {
    this.pointSW = sw;
    this.pointNE = ne;
  }
  
  public double getWidth() {
    return Math.abs(this.pointNE.x - this.pointSW.x);
  }
  public double getHeight() {
    return Math.abs(this.pointSW.y - this.pointNE.y);
  }
  public void setWidth(final double width) {
    this.pointNE.x = this.point.SW.x + width;
  }
  public void setHeight(final double eight) {
    this.pointNE.y = this.point.SW.y + eight;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your time! and yes i did it this way but when  i wrote the  setWidth() for instance and use getWidth() to define it and when i run the tester it shows me an error and says (NOTE: check if you've set a new value to pointNE) how can i fix this?

Comment: It depends, you need a constraint when you're setting a width/height, because there are infinite couple of points which can give you a rectangle with same height and width (translation of the rectangle). So you need, for example, to specify if with the new height/width, you want to keep the pointSW or the pointNE constant (for example). In other words, when you want to increase the width, you want to move left, or right? When you want to increase the width, you want move up or down? The program can't know itself, you must specify it, or you need to do it "randomly"

Comment: right. the south-west point should remain at its place and the north-east point should move. i thought about writing; int x1, int y1, and then x1 is the x or the NE point plus getWidth() and y1 is the y of NE plus getHeight() and then _pointNE = new Point (x1,y1) but it also shows me an error, but technically i can use getWidth() in setWidth() for example right? how would you write the setWidth() method? ( public void setWidth(int w) {}) also if the parameter isnt a positive number nothing should change. its all way easier with _width and _height as variables eh

Comment: @Gius, possibly the absolute value of differences should be used when calculating width and height: `Math.abs(pointNE.x - pointSW.x)` etc. because directions are not set here and therefore scalar width and height may become negative (e.g. for Y axis from south to north and for X axis from west to east).

Comment: @Miri yes, I added setter methods to the code

Comment: i wrote the setWidth(int w) method like this: this._pointNE.getX()  = this._pointSW.getX() + w; and it doesnt compile cause of the first part, where's .getX(), it says "unexpected type required variable, found value". im using Bluej (thats just the platform we use in the course) what can be the reason for it and is there a way to make it work?

Comment: its all fine now, works as it should. thanks alot.