# How can i setup a variable inside a constructor and use a "getter" method later on in the program on it? (Java)

Tags: java, constructor

I am stuck on my assignment and could use some help

In the instance variables section we are only allowed to use the following:

```java
private int _width;
private int _height;
private Point _pointSW; // point is basically (x,y)
```

I have created a constructor but I am now confused on how can I create a _pointNW variable inside the constructor that I can later use in a "getter" method, here is my constructor, do note that I am not sure how to create _pointNW properly since its the first time I have no private variable to connect them so I am clueless on how exactly to do this properly and I was also worried about aliasing so I'm not sure if I had to use new here:

```java
public RectangleA(Point sw, Point ne) {
    _pointSW = new Point(sw);
    Point _pointNW = new Point(ne);
}
```

I am not allowed to add `_pointNW` to the private section so it also confused me how exactly do I set it up in the constructor so I can in the end use it in a getter?

in the end I am supposed to retrieve that `_pointNW` to be used in the following "getter" :

```java
public Point getPointNE(){ }
```

Anyone can help? been trying stuff out for an hour and can't figure out how to do this...

Comment: Apparently you are supposed to do something like `width=ne.x-sw.x;` and `height=ne.y-sw.y;`, and later reconstruct `ne` when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the idea of the assignment is to create a getter for the NE point without storing.  That means you will have to store the information you need to calculate that point in the getter.  You can use height and width to do this:

```
import java.awt.Point;
public class RectangleA {
    private int _width;
    private int _height;
    private Point _pointSW;   

    public RectangleA(Point sw, Point ne) {
        // This assumes (0,0) is in the nw corner
        this._pointSW = new Point(sw); // Save the coordinates of the sw point
        this._width = ne.x - sw.x; // Save the width based on the difference between the two points' x values
        this._height = sw.y - ne.y; // Save the height based on the difference in y values
    }
    public Point getPointNE() {
        // We don't store the ne point so we calculate it based on the sw point and the height and width
        int neX = this._pointSW.x + this._width; // The sw x + width is the ne X coordinate
        int neY = this._pointSW.y - this._height; // The sw y - height is the ne Y coordinate
        Point result = new Point( neX, neY ); // construct that point and return it
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a new instance variable.  But it seems you don't want to do that due to the assignment.

The other way is to calculate it in the getter.  You have the SW point, the width, and the height.  So you can either add or subtract the width and height to figure out the NE point.  Whether you add or subtract would depend on where the origin is, you didn't specify.

Answer (score 1):

So you have N/E (top/right) and S/W (bottom/left), N/W (top/left) is a combination of these two, for example

```
public Point getPointNW() {
    return new Point(_sw.x, _ne.y);
}
```